# Understanding Error.captureStackTrace and stack trace persistance?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I a while ago i used to use Verror from joyent to not lose the stacktrace when rethrowing, I have just done a test with node v12 without Verror and stack trace seems to be persisted without the use of error.

I then was looking at the use of Error.captureStackTrace, it states to use this in your errors so that the Error is not added to the stack.

I don't what i am doing wrong but with or without Error.captureStackTrace   - the stack trace is the same..

I would like to know the current status of the use of the captureStackTrace as i see no difference :-) and also the use of VError that doesn't seem to be needed anymore.

In the documentation it states that the .stack isn't available without calling the captureStackTrace but I see it available each time, with or without the captureStackTrace

here is an example of 2 x errors

```
class MyErrorOne extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

class MyErrorTwo extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}
```

I tried them by commenting out the captureStackTrace in EACH error and the stacktrace is the same.

Can anyone help ?

Here is my code to test calling the errors

```
const DoOne = () => {
  try {
    console.log("executing do one");
    DoTwo();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in DoOne", error);
    console.log("here is the stack ", error.stack);
    throw new MyErrorOne("threw error from doone in myerrorone");
    // throw error;
  }
};

const DoTwo = () => {
  try {
    console.log("executing do two");
    throw new MyErrorTwo("threw error from dotwo in myerrortwo");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in DoTwo", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

DoOne();
```

Answer (score 33):

When calling `Error.captureStackTrace(obj[, fun])` a formatted call stack is attached to `obj` including the line/frame where `captureStackTrace` was called.

When specifying `fun` all frames above and including `fun` are removed.

### Examples:

*Note: In sample outputs I have removed anything below call to `fun1` to minimize clutter.*

```js
const fun1 = () => { fun2(); };
const fun2 = () => { fun3(); };
const fun3 = () => { log_stack(); };
function log_stack() {
    let err = {};
    Error.captureStackTrace(err);
    console.log(err.stack);
}
fun1();
```

This yields:

```
Error
    at log_stack (/path/to/example.js:6:8)
    at fun3 (/path/to/example.js:3:22)
    at fun2 (/path/to/example.js:2:22)
    at fun1 (/path/to/example.js:1:22)
```

Now, if we add `log_stack` as the function option to `captureStackTrace`:

```
Error.captureStackTrace(err, log_stack);
```

It yields:

```
Error
    at fun3 (/path/to/example.js:3:22)
    at fun2 (/path/to/example.js:2:22)
    at fun1 (/path/to/example.js:1:22)
```

The `log_stack` frame is not there anymore.

Adding `fun3` to the `captureStackTrace`:

```
Error.captureStackTrace(err, fun3);
```

It yields:

```
Error
    at fun2 (/path/to/example.js:2:22)
    at fun1 (/path/to/example.js:1:22)
```

Etc.

In your case, if you change:

```
Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
```

to:

```
Error.captureStackTrace(this);
```

You will see that you get an additional line with the `new MyError...`:

```
error in DoTwo MyErrorTwo: threw error from dotwo in myerrortwo
    at new MyErrorTwo (/path/to/testerrorclass.js:10:9)  <<== Not removed anymore.
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure, but it seems that `Error.captureStackTrace` is intended to be used when constructing Error object without extending the `Error` class (see also the example provided in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_capturestacktrace_targetobject_constructoropt).

I'm guessing that when you're extending the `Error` class, capturing the stack trace is already done by the Error constructor.

I've tested your code and remove the extending of Error and indeed if you don't call `captureStackTrace` you will not get a stack trace on your error objects.

I'm not sure what would be the use case of throwing Errors that are not extending the Error class.

Answer (score 1):

`captureStackTrace` returns a string that represents the location of that particular error in the call. It gives us a stack that helps us to find the location of that error in the code at which `new Error()` was Called. this will help us to find the exact error in our code.

I am not sure which documentation you mention, but if you read [V8 stack trace docs](https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api)

```
Error.captureStackTrace(error, constructorOpt)
```

> adds a stack property to the given error object that yields the stack
> trace at the time captureStackTrace was called. Stack traces collected
> through Error.captureStackTrace are immediately collected, formatted,
> and attached to the given error object.
>
> The optional constructorOpt parameter allows you to pass in a function
> value. When collecting the stack trace all frames above the topmost
> call to this function, including that call, are left out of the stack
> trace. This can be useful to hide implementation details that won’t be
> useful to the user. The usual way of defining a custom error that
> captures a stack trace would be:

```
function MyError() {
      // if you are calling this in constructor, instead of MyError, "this.constructor"
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, MyError);
      // Any other initialization goes here.
    }
```

> Passing in MyError as a second argument means that the constructor
> call to MyError won’t show up in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation that I found a while back, the key is to restore the prototype chain (typescript):

```
import {INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR} from 'http-status-codes';

export class RouteError extends Error {
  public statusCode: number;
  /**
   * Create a new RouteError object to be handled in 'express-async-handler' wrapped middleware.
   * @param message {string} [message=An error occurred.] - The json message key to return to the user.
   * @param statusCode {number} [statusCode=INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR] - response code to send.
   */
  constructor(message: string = 'An error occurred.', statusCode: number = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
    super(message); // 'Error' breaks prototype chain here
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype); // restore prototype chain
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
}
```